# Using collection filters on frontend templates in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

is it possible to use in the frontend templates the same filters we use in the backend grids for example?
I'm using magento 2.1.5.

Comment: Yes, You can ,but Please tell which collection you want use

Comment: I have a method in my Block class that get a list of some items using "model"->getCollection() on the frontend ,  I want to use in my method the built-in filters so I can filter my data.